# Trying to use views in django like I use to used in python

Tags: python, django, django-views

why it does not work ?
It suppose to work, in python I can use this like this function, can any one explain me please ?

**views:**

```
class MiVista(View):
    def get(self, request, var):
        self.var = 'Hello'
        # <la logica de la vista>
        return HttpResponse(self.var)

one = MiVista()
one.get(222222)
```

**urls:**

```
url(r'^indice/', MiVista.as_view()),
```

So the functions does not work like function in python using POO ?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Yes, they do. But just like any other function in python you need to pass right arguments. In your case get() takes two arguments and you are passing it one. And on top of that you are not passing the second argument in your urls.

Answer (score 1):

So as @MadWombat mentioned, you are not passing enough arguments, so you need to pass `self`, which already passing by calling from instance objects, `request`(not passing), `var`(passing). And as you are not providing that you are passing `var=2222`, python thinks that `2222` is `request` argument.

So basically you need to create `request` argument. You can do this with [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory). Like that

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.views.generic import View


class MiVista(View):
    def get(self, request, var):
        self.var = var
        # <la logica de la vista>
        return HttpResponse(self.var)

rf = RequestFactory()
rf.get('indice/')

one = MiVista.as_view()(rf, var='hello')
```